# Buzz in speakers after suspend/resume

Tags: 16.04, sound, suspend, pulseaudio

After suspend/resume, there's a quite loudly buzz in the speakers of my computer (or, to be more exact, in the speakers of my monitor, plugged in HDMI). For its part, my bluetooth headset isn't concerned.

It's not a big deal to stop it, I just have to launch the Pulseaudio volume control panel ('pavucontrol')... and that's all.

I've noticed the same thing happens when the computer boots, I hear a buzz during the loading sequence, which then stops itself when LightDM displays.

I really don't understand what could explain that, and I've found nothing on the web. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

[Ubuntu 16.04.4]